# Possible to use Co-Authoring via Excel Interop?

Tags: development, excel

When editing an Excel workbook stored on SharePoint / OneDrive via Excel Interop (C# automation): can several agents co-author the file like multiple Excel users can?

As a minimum, I require one human editor and one automated / interop instance. The human should be able to see the changes that the automation makes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works (in hindsight: why shouldn't it). I tried it with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 16 (not available via NuGet but available in the COM references when Excel 2016 or greater is installed).

Without any special programming, coauthoring can be used after opening the shared workbook (.xlsx on Sharepoint, just use the http path as argument in the Open command). Any automated updates will swiftly appear for the coauthors.